# How to find the body and the subject in a mailto link?

Tags: ruby, uri, mailto

I have this mailto link :

`mailto:email@address.com?&subject=test&body=type%20your&body=message%20here`

I would like to find `to`, `subject`, `body`.

Actually I use :

```
uri = URI('mailto:email@address.com?&subject=test&body=type%20your&body=message%20here')
```

> `<URI::MailTo mailto:email@address.com?&subject=test&body=type%20your&body=message%20here>`

I have :to with that :
`uri.to`

but I can not extract `subject` and `body`.

Do you know how to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`URI::MailTo#headers`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/MailTo.html#headers-attribute-method) which returns an array of arrays:

```
uri.headers
#=> [[], ["subject", "test"], ["body", "type%20your"], ["body", "message%20here"]]
```

However, your mailto link is slightly broken. It should look like this:

```
uri = URI('mailto:email@address.com?subject=test&body=type%20your%0D%0Amessage%20here')
#                                   ^                            ^
#                               no '&' here                newline as %0D%0A
```

That gives:

```
uri.headers
#=> [["subject", "test"], ["body", "type%20your%0D%0Amessage%20here"]]
```

Which can be accessed via `assoc`:

```
uri.headers.assoc('subject').last
#=> "test"
```

Or be converted to a hash:

```
headers = uri.headers.to_h
#=> {"subject"=>"test", "body"=>"type%20your%0D%0Amessage%20here"}
```

To get decoded values:

```
URI.decode_www_form_component(headers['body'])
#=> "type your\r\nmessage here"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer
Actually, that's how I do it for the moment but it's ugly and I think it's not very stable depending on the format. Deplus, we have a great tool (URI) and I think there is more simple. I would like to be able to do `uri.subject` & `uri.body`

Comment: @HugoBarthelemy `URI` provides `decode_www_form_component` but I think you have to call it yourself. I've updated my answer accordingly.